# Бот, который проверяет изменения html кода сайта

Tags: python, html, telegram-bot

Я хочу создать телеграм бота на python, который будет отправлять уведомление в случае изменения html кода определённого сайта. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Периодически парсить сайт и сравнивать?